# Playing Videos from Picasa Albums

Tags: zend-framework, video, picasa

I am using Zend Framework to show photos from Picasa Web Albums. My questions is how to display videos if there is any in the album?

```
  foreach ($albumFeed as $albumEntry) {

    if ($albumEntry->getMediaGroup() != null) {

      $mediaArray = $albumEntry->getMediaGroup()->getContent();
      if (sizeof($mediaArray) > 1)  {
        foreach($mediaArray as $mediaEntry) {
          if ($mediaEntry->getMedium() == 'video')  {
            $media = 'video';
            $videoSrc = $mediaEntry->getUrl();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The $videoSrc has the video link but how can I play the video?

I tried something like:

echo "<object width='400' height='255'\>
        <embed src='http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?videoUrl=$videoSrc'
           type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always'
            width='410' height='255'></embed>
      </object>";

but it didn't work. Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Picasa video links expire after a short period of time, which means you can't. You could upload from Picasa to YouTube, but that's a pain if you're getting data from the API's

Comment: Thanks Ashley. They have an expiry date but I expect that I can play them right after I retrieve them from Picasa Web Albums.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code to display the video, but they will leave after 11 hours (-;

```
<object width="425" height="355">
    <param name="movie" 
           value="YOUR_VIDEO_URL">
    </param>

    <param name="wmode" 
           value="transparent">
    </param>

    <embed src="YOUR_VIDEL_URL" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I tried it but no video. The video link is: http://v19.nonxt8.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=61efd1105619fa95&amp;itag=5&amp;begin=0&amp;len=2147483647&amp;app=picasa&amp;et=INVALID&amp;el=INVALID&amp;ip=0.0.0.0&amp;ipbits=0&amp;expire=2882111679&amp;sparams=id,itag,ip,ipbits,expire&amp;signature=47FA67E350034755A1AFD04C703346DD60E8B98.E02F6F5838CFF49358A0986058588AEF216CCFE&amp;key=ck1<br/>It just displays a blank page. Thank you. I appreciate the answer.